# Two Linux user accounts, one domain name

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, virtualhost

Bit of an odd request, but Im really desperate for some advice. Im Using CentOS 7 w/ CentOS WebPanel and Apache.

I have 2 seperate linux user accounts. I have a single website https://example.com and a subdomain https://store.example.com

Currently, the vhost DocumentRoots are /home/foo1/public_html & /home/foo1/store

I need both of the linux accounts to have access to the website. Should I move my website documentroots outside of the /home/ folder? To something like /var/www/?
How would that work, would both accounts be able to access files on the website?
Do I need to set up a group for that? What is the best practice for this situation?

I appriciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 2):

Create a user group, add those 2 users to this group, let us call it "Managers". then add needed permissions to this group of users. you can add as many users to that group as needed. it will be the most efficient and secure approach which will let you scale if your admin group grows.